# How can I re-enable a text field?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-enable a text field that gets automatically filled in and disabled on the website we use for ticketing. It is currently possible to inspect element, and enable manually to field to enter anything you want. I'd like to remove that step. I am trying to make a (very) simple chrome extension that will detect when the field has been disabled and switch it back on, but I'm having no luck.

I've tried several iterations, with no success. Here's what I've got at the 
moment.

```
var subject = document.getElementById('title_fs');
subject.onchange = function() {fix()}
function fix(){
    subject.setAttribute("enabled", true)}
```

I also tried

```
var subject = document.getElementById('title_fs');
subject.addEventListener("change", {subject.setAttribute("disabled", false)});
```

The most success I've had so far was accidentally disabling the field as soon as the page loaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you used `removeAttribute("disabled")` method on your element ?

Comment: I have, but did not have any luck. Part of the problem is that it starts off enabled, but after a few choices are made it gets auto-filled and then disabled. I'm trying to make something that with stop or reverse the disabling after the page has been loaded for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the attribute

```
document.getElementById('title_fs').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

```js
document.getElementById('removeDisabled').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('title_fs').removeAttribute('disabled');
});
```

```html
<textarea disabled="true" id="title_fs">Foobar</textarea>
<button id="removeDisabled">Remove Disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.disabled = true/false
```

```js
function func() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('someId');
  elem.disabled = !elem.disabled;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="someId" />
<button onclick="func();">click</button>
```